# C# generic interface covariance

Tags: c#, generics, covariance

I have an interface `IControl<IModel>`

I am using it in a generic class `SomeClass<TModel> where TModel:IModel`, 
so the generic type parameter `TModel` is derived from `IModel`.

I have a method

```
SetControl(IControl<IModel> control){
   IControl<IModel> c = control;
   ....
```

But I'm getting a compiler error:

`Error  9   Cannot implicitly convert type 'X.Y.IControl<TModel>' to 'X.Y.IControl<X.Y.IModel>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)`

I suspect this has to do with variance, so I've tried to change my interface declaration to be covariant - according to [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) *Covariance -  Enables you to use a more specific type than originally specified.*

I've declared the interface as   `public interface IControl<out T> where T : IModel`, but that did not help. What am I missing?

Comment: I think you need to use `in`.

Comment: Is this your real code? The error message suggests that `control` is actually declared as `IControl<TModel> control`. The code you have posted should work since `c` and `control` are the exact same type.

Comment: @Lee given the error message I assume that's a typo.

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing `SetControl` is actually declared as:

```
public class SomeClass<TModel> where TModel : IModel
{
    SetControl(IControl<TModel> control) { ... }
}
```

in this case you need to add a `class` constraint to `TModel` if `IControl<T>` is covariant:

```
public class SomeClass<TModel> where TModel : class, IModel
{
    SetControl(IControl<TModel> control)
    {
        IControl<IModel> c = control;
    }
}
```