# Why doesn't C# covariance work properly with interface type constraints?

Tags: c#, generics, interface, covariance, variance

Here is a code snippet that I have tested on dotnet fiddle on all 3 available compilers:

```cs
using System;

interface Foo<out T1>{ }
interface Baz<out T1>{ }

public class Program
{
    abstract class A {}
    class B : A {}
    
    class Bar<T> : Foo<Baz<T>>{}
    
    static void takeConcrete(Foo<Baz<A>> arg) {}
    
    static void take<T>(Foo<Baz<T>> arg) where T : A 
    {
        takeConcrete(arg);
    }
    
    public static void Main()
    {
        take(new Bar<B>());
    }
}
```

Now, this compiles flawlessly, as expected. But when I change the definition of A to be `interface A {}`, then it stops compiling:

```cs
using System;

interface Foo<out T1>{ }
interface Baz<out T1>{ }

public class Program
{
    interface A {} // <-- change here
    class B : A {}
    
    class Bar<T> : Foo<Baz<T>>{}
    
    static void takeConcrete(Foo<Baz<A>> arg) {}
    
    static void take<T>(
        Foo<Baz<T>> arg
    ) where T : A {
        takeConcrete(arg); // <-- compiler error here
    }
    
    public static void Main()
    {
        take(new Bar<B>());
    }
}
```

The compiler error is the following:

> Argument 1: cannot convert from `Foo<Baz<T>>` to `<Foo<Baz<Program.A>>`

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24910545/c-sharp-generic-interface-covariance) there seems to be a missing `: class` constraint. And indeed, if I constrain `T` in the `take` method to `where T : class, A`, then it compiles again.

Still, I am wondering: why is this `class` constraint necessary? As far as I understand C#, interface references are boxed on the heap no matter what, so it really shouldn't matter. If the implementing type happens to be a struct, then there will be only one valid type, but that sounds like something the JIT compiler should be able to figure out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If `T` is a struct, then generic type replacement means that the *actual* (or constructed) type of `T` *is* the struct, it is *not* a boxed interface representation of it.**

Therefore covariance cannot be used if `T` is not constrained to be a class, because an unboxed struct does not inherit from anything (even from `System.Object`), and it does not have any representation that can be used like a reference type.

---

**Let us suppose that `T` is a struct `MyStruct`.** Your code now becomes:

```cs
    static void take(Foo<Baz<MyStruct>> arg) {
        takeConcrete(arg);
    }
```

But the code for `takeConcrete` is defined:

```cs
    static void takeConcrete(Foo<Baz<A>> arg) {}
```

In other words, it expects a *boxed* `A` representation, and `MyStruct` in this context is not boxed.

---

**Proving the point,** all code that uses a generic type that is constrained to an interface but *not* `class` will compile with the `constrained.callvirt` instruction in IL. This is to prevent unnecessary boxing.

Comment: Thanks! Short and precise. Learned something new today. Always interesting to see tradeoffs between programmer convenience and performance.

Comment: One follow-up question: how does `consteained.callvirt` prevent boxing? Do you have any resources to read up on where and how boxing happens?

Comment: [ECMA-335](https://www.ecma-international.org/wp-content/uploads/ECMA-335_6th_edition_june_2012.pdf) is a very interesting document, the spec that defines everything you need to know about the CLR and IL. Section III.2.1 for `constrained`, you may also find II.9 informative on generics, if rather complex